# Probability of Each team winning Knockout tournament

Tags: probability

How can we solve this kind of question using Computer programming?

There are 2^n teams.
teams compete with each other like knockout.
For example if there are 64 teams, then the next only 32 teams left, then 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 ->1.

A matrix, P[i][j] means the probability i will win when i vs j.

What is the probability that each team wins the tournament ？

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account that for `2^n` teams, there are `n` rounds. Each round is an independent event.

Since they compete **1 vs 1**, a team has **50%** or (1/2) of probabilites to win a round.

So let's imagine that there are `2^3` teams, it means there would be **3 rounds** and **8 teams**. Imagine we are in `team 1`.

- Probabilities for us to win the **first** round is `1/2`.
- Probabilities to win the **sencond** round is `(1/2)/2`.
- Probabilities to win the **final** round is `[(1/2)/2]/2`.

In fact, probabilities to win the competition are `[(1/2)/2]/2`, or `1/8` or `1/(2^3)`.

**Conclusion**: probabilities to win are `1/(2^n)`.

---

In computer programming, you can check the probabilities this way:

```js
const n = 3 // Rounds -> Means 2^n teams

/* Do 10000 competitions in order to check
   if the probabilities are correct */
const competitions = 10000;  

// Array where store 100 competitions results
const results = Array( Math.pow(2,n) ); 
// Put each result into initial value 0
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i ++) {
  results[i] = 0;
}

// Perforn competitions
for(let c = 0; c < competitions; c++) {

  // Creating teams
  const teams = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.pow(2,n); i++) {   // Create 2^n teams
    teams.push(i);
  }

  // Performs n rounds
  for (let round = 0; round < n; round++) {
    
    // Perform games 1 vs 1. If n = 3
    // First round => 4 games (Quarters)
    // Second round => 2 games (Semis)
    // Third round => 1 game (Final)   
    const desqualified = [];
    for (let game = 0; game < Math.pow(2, n - 1 - round); game++) {
    
      // Get random number between 0 and 1
      const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      
      // Desqualify team depending on the rnd value
      desqualified.push(game * 2 + rnd);
    }
   
   // After each round erase desqualified teams
   for (let i = 0; i < desqualified.length; i++) {
    teams.splice(desqualified[i] - i, 1);
   }
  }
  // Store result
  results[teams[0] - 1]++;

}

// Display results
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i ++) {
  const percentage = ((results[i] * 100) / competitions).toFixed(3) + "%";
  console.log("Team " + (i + 1) + " won " + results[i] + " times: " + percentage);
}
```

You can check that results are around `12%` and `13%` for each team, which is in accordance with `1/(2^n)`

Comment: Thanks but where are you making use of 2D matrix storing probability between 2 teams?

Comment: And what's the rationale behind 10000 competition?

Comment: I change it to 10000 competitions to see better the 1/(2^n) probabilities. If you are working with knockout format, the probability between 2 teams to won is 1/2 always. Or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: When Team i and j compete there is a Probability P[i][j] that team i beat j. Somewhere this information to be used.